# I am looking to convert this cURL command into NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cookies, curl, httprequest, spiceworks

I am working with Spiceworks, a multipurpose IT tool and am trying to create a script to update our product keys in the database. I am not very experience with NodeJS so I am pretty confused how to create the equivalent to this curl command:

> curl
>   'https://spiceworks.elogicgroup.com/software_licenses.js?device_view=true'
>   \
>
> -H 'Cookie: spiceworks_session=**BAh7F...9ffe**' \
>
> -H 'Origin: https://spiceworks.elogicgroup.com' \
>
> -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----BOUNDARY' \
>
> -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
>
> --data-binary $'------BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition:
>   form-data;name="authenticity_token"\r\n\r\ **blfbEi...cK+/k=**
>   \r\n------BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="_pickaxe"\r\n\r\n\u2e15\r\n------BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition:
>   form-data; name="software_license[software_id]"\r\n\r\n
>   **513**\r\n------BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="software_installation"\r\n\r\n
>   **3854**\r\n------BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="software_license[type]"\r\n\r\nIndividualLicense\r\n------BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition:
>   form-data; name="software_license[key]"\r\n\r\n
>   **54321**\r\n------BOUNDARY--\r\n'

**BAh7F...9ffe** is your SpiceWorks session cookie.

**blfbEi...cK+/k** is an authentication token.

**513** is the ID of the software application

**3854** ties the software application to a specific install on a specific computer

I would really appreciate any tips or directions you all could point me in, I am really struggling with this.

Thanks!!
Jack

Answer (score 1):

Using https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
var r = request.post({
  url: 'https://spiceworks.elogicgroup.com/software_licenses.js?device_view=true',
  headers: {
    'Cookie': 'spiceworks_session=BAh7F...9ffe',
    'Origin': 'https://spiceworks.elogicgroup.com/',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0' 
  }
});

var form = r.form();
form.append('authenticity_token', 'blfbEi...cK+/k');
. . .
```

Comment: Hi, I am following your suggestions but am still having issues. This is where I am:  http://imgur.com/wq1mwxK